# Drupal Views does not show some nodes

Tags: drupal, view

I have a view that has the following settings:

> Style: Unformatted
>
> styleRow style: Fields
>
> ...
>
> Filters
>
> Node: Published Yes
>
> Node: Type = Image
>
> Node revision: Title begins
>   slideshow_q
>
> ...
>
> Fields
>
> Node: Title Title
>
> Image: Image Image

I also have 6 image nodes. Yet only one of them--the fifth one!--is showing up in my view. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: here is the [exported view](http://gist.github.com/460506) for a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the nodes in question are not published, or they are not a type Image, or their title does not begin with 'slideshow_q'.

Try removing the Published filter and see what the result is.

EDIT: Try removing the Node Revision filter. I thought it said Node.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, they are all published nodes and they all start with 'slideshow_q'. So those filters should catch them all, but they catch only one among the set.

Comment: Removing all filters other than Image returns nothing?

Comment: Removing all filters returns just one image. And it's the first image I added to the system.

Comment: Kevin, I exported the view so you can look at it. This is what it looks like: http://gist.github.com/460506